# One command to get output buffer and erase it in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any command to get the output and erase the buffer **without** turning it off?

eg.

```
ob_start();
include 'first_page.php';
$first_page = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
include 'second_page.php';
$second_page = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
....
```

Is there a function available so I don't have to turn on output buffering every time?

Comment: No, but is executing two commands such an overhead on your system? ob_get_contents() followed by ob_clean()

Comment: @MarkBaker Not at all, but it sure makes the code cleaner and less prone to errors if I forget to clean the buffer.

Comment: Create your own function `ob_get_clean_dontclose() { $result=ob_get_contents(); ob_clean(); return $result; }` then just call that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for an answer to this question and wanted to post the answer based on comments posted here.

---

It looks like the answer is **no**, there is no single command to get the output buffer and erase it without turning it off. However, instead of repeatedly starting a new buffer, you could just erase the current buffer with `ob_clean()` in between calls of `ob_get_contents()`

For example:

```
ob_start();
include 'first_page.php';
$first_page = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
include 'second_page.php';
$second_page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```